# Why is ping not being sent to IRC?

Tags: c#, ping, server, irc

I am receiving a ping from the IRC server and I am trying to reply to it but when I send the pong to reply to the ping my IRC client still times out. If I am sending it wrong could someone show me how to properly send it.

```
                for (; ; )
                {
                    var rec = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(rec);
                    //Replies to ping message
                    if (rec.StartsWith("PING"))
                    {
                        writer.Write("PONG :asimov.freenode.net");
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop reading from the stream `reader.Read(readBuf, 0, readBuf.Length)` while later you use `reader.ReadLine` ?  AFAIK that loop won't break until an exception, and at which point reader.ReadLine's behavior will be unpredictable.  How far in to the stream did the previous Read go before you ReadLine?  Did you debug this and put a breakpoint to see what the contents of `string line` is after ReadLine?

Comment: For most of your writes, you explicitly `Flush` the writer after. But you don't do that for the PING/PONG case. That could be the cause.

Comment: @AaronLS So what do you supposed I do and do you have any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ike I made a suggestion on how to debug as well as asked some clarifying questions. I assume there's a reason you chose to use a buffered read loop in addition to the ReadLine loop. Can you explain why you coded it this way?  You have to understand your code before you can debug it.

Comment: @AaronLS I have no exact reason for why I had coded it that way the first time. I guess it was just bad programming. I am still sort of new to programming so I guess it's ok. I fixed it now though.

Comment: Are you sure that the string received after PING is "asimov.frenode.net"? The correct (according to spec) way is to send back exactly what you receive from the server. Thus, if you receive "PING :foobarbaz" you have to send back "PONG :foobarbaz". You appear to discard the value sent by the server and always reply with a hard-coded value.

Comment: Does this help? writer.Write("PONG :asimov.freenode.net\n"); in my case:  self.irc_sock.send(bytes('PONG %s\r\n' %(_pong), 'UTF-8'))

Answer (score 0):

1st.
Parse out the Parameter "asimov.freenode.net" from the PING-Command what is coming from the IRC-Server.

2nd.
Send back this Parameter with a PONG   "PONG :asimov.freenode.net" inside a predefined amount of time, if you not answer inside this timespan (for ex. 120 sec.), the IRC-Server will disconnecting your Client.